# iOS Core Data change the name of the Sqlite file in Document Director

Tags: swift, core-data, migration

Accidentally I changed the name of the site file, and I think this is why I lost my data of the previous version:

```
/* CORE DATA */

// MARK: - Core Data stack

lazy var applicationDocumentsDirectory: URL = {
    let urls = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
    return urls[urls.count-1]
}()

lazy var managedObjectModel: NSManagedObjectModel = {
    let modelURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "solutis", withExtension: "momd")!
    return NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOf: modelURL)!
}()

lazy var persistentStoreCoordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator = {
    let coordinator = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: self.managedObjectModel)
    let url = self.applicationDocumentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("solutis.sqlite")
    var failureReason = "There was an error creating or loading the application's saved data."
    do {
        let options = [NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption:true, NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption:true]
        try coordinator.addPersistentStore(ofType: NSSQLiteStoreType, configurationName: nil, at: url, options: options)
    } catch let error as NSError {
        var dict = [String: AnyObject]()
        dict[NSLocalizedDescriptionKey] = "Failed to initialize the application's saved data" as AnyObject?
        dict[NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey] = failureReason as AnyObject?
        dict[NSUnderlyingErrorKey] = error
        let wrappedError = NSError(domain: "YOUR_ERROR_DOMAIN", code: 9999, userInfo: dict)
        NSLog("Unresolved error \(wrappedError), \(wrappedError.userInfo)")
        abort()
    } catch {
        fatalError()
    }

    return coordinator
}()


lazy var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext = {
    let coordinator = self.persistentStoreCoordinator
    var managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .mainQueueConcurrencyType)
    managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = coordinator
    return managedObjectContext
}()

// MARK: - Core Data Saving support

func saveContext () {
    if managedObjectContext.hasChanges {
        do {
            try managedObjectContext.save()
        } catch {
            let nserror = error as NSError
            NSLog("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
            abort()
        }
    }
}
```

I found subjects about and I want to know if I put this:

```
    if !FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: (url.path)) {
        let seededUrl = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "MY_APP_NAME", withExtension: "sqlite")
        try! FileManager.default.copyItem(at: seededUrl!, to: url)
    }
```

The app will get the old data and use the new sqlite file ?

Comment: What journal mode were you using previously?  If WAL mode (the default since iOS7), you will need also to copy the WAL and SHM files.